# How do I style a react component based on multiple conditions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I have a List of products with their expiry dates. I want to apply styles depending on whether my item is going to expire today, not expire today or has already expired.(There could be many more conditions which I want to work with).
I have successfully managed to do it using **nested ternary operator** or using an **array of styles with ternary operator** as shown below.

```
 <ListItem  
     containerStyle={
          [exp_check === -1 ? { backgroundColor: '#ff9ea5' } : null,
                exp_check === 0 ? { backgroundColor: '#fff185' } : null]
                    }
     badge={
          exp_check !== 1 ?
               exp_check === -1 ? { status: 'error', value: `!` } : { status: 'warning'} : null
           }
/>
```

---

Is there a way to achieve something like a **switch** statement for the style or for any other prop for that matter. I want to be able to easily set my props conditionally without having to write nested logic or arrays. Something along the lines of :

```
stlye / badge / any prop accepted by the component = {
switch(something):
CASE1: ..
CASE2:.. 
etc etc 
CASE N:
}
```

I am not sure if I can write an IF/ELSE statement inside the prop because I have not been able to get it to compile if I try to do that.

Comment: Why not compute it before the render? Complex logic belongs in places suited for complex logic.

Comment: How do I do that ? I think I can make my expiry checking function return a string and access my stylesheet object using that string but it still feels hacky.

Comment: Put it in the code before you start rendering? It's not clear what the ultimate issue is.

Comment: Yeah I got it I was just staring at the screen too long I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an approach where you have a categorization function that bins a given item into a particular group, then map props or styles or classnames onto the groups.

```js
const ONE_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const ONE_DAY = ONE_HOUR * 24;

// an array of status names/labels, each with a predicate function
// to test whether a given item matches. first match wins.
const bins = [
  {
    status: 'expired',
    predicate: time => time < Date.now(),
  },
  {
    status: 'urgent',
    predicate: time => Date.now() - time < ONE_HOUR
  },
  {
    status: 'soon',
    predicate: time => Date.now() - time < ONE_DAY,
  },
  {
    status: 'normal'
    predicate: () => true
  }
}

// find the first bin whose predicate function returns true for the item and use that bin's 'status'
const expirationStatus = bins.find(bin => bin.predicate(item.expirationTime)).status;

// now expirationStatus is one of 'expired', 'urgent', 'soon', or 'normal'
// which you can then use to assign styles or classNames or whatever:

// these could live in the bins too, as a 'style' or 'className' property or whatever.
const styles = {
  expired: {
    background: 'grey',
  },
  urgent: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  soon: {
    background: 'yellow'
  },
  normal: {
    background: 'green'
  }
}

return (
  <Component
    style={styles[expirationStatus]} {/* this */}
    status={expirationStatus} {/* and/or this */}
    className={expirationStatus} {/* and/or this */}
  />
)
```

Comment: Thanks I did something similar.